# Surveys with Export to Excel option

Tags: 2010, excel, export, survey

How do I ensure that once I create a survey in SP 2010 that I'm able to export the resposes to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the Survey you will see that Option OOTB under the `Actions` dropdown. see this image.

[image]

Their are chances that this option is not aviable or working. in order to troubleshoot that issue. see below some tips.

- You should have office application (Office 2010/Office 2007) should
  be installed on your client machine.
- Make sure that 'SharePoint Server Enterprise Site
  Collection features' should be activated at the site collection
  level.
- Are you logged in as site collection admin or site owner? What are
  your permissions on the site? Also, try opening IE in "Run as
  administrator" mode and see if that makes a difference.
- Make sure that you have to check the option (i.e. export to
  spreadsheet) on a actual survey list and not on a web part
- make sure that on the Survey page, the view on right-hand corner is
  set to "Overview"
- See more at: http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2012/07/export-to-spreadsheet-is-missing-in.html#.VYGKlPlVhCY